# python if statement returns value error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry to ask this apparently simple question, but I am a python beginner and couln't find an answer anywhere. I want to run a simple if statement, but python returns just:

```
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

No matter which of the given alternatives I apply - it just doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None] * 4, 'b': [2, 3, 10, 3]})

    df["c"] =0    
    if df.b == 2:
        df.c =1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare a scalar with an array like that using `if` it becomes ambiguous as what if one of the values matches or all but one you want to do something like:

```
In [3]:

df['c'] = np.where(df['b'] == 2, 1, np.NaN)
df
Out[3]:
      a   b   c
0  None   2   1
1  None   3 NaN
2  None  10 NaN
3  None   3 NaN
```

using `np.where` looks at the whole array for that condition and if `True` returns `1`, otherwise `NaN`

You can perform comparisons using syntax like:

```
In [4]:

df['b'] == 2
Out[4]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

but not using `if` unless you are comparing a single value:

```
In [8]:

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['b'] == 2:
        print('equals 2')
    else:
        print('some other value')
equals 2
some other value
some other value
some other value
```

Answer (score 3):

In `if` statement you're trying to compare an array with scalar. You can use something like

```
if df.b[0] == 2:
    df.c =1
```

or

```
if 2 in df.b:
    df.c =1
```

if you want to check for a specific element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You set `df.b` to be a list containing four numbers. It can never equal a single number.

And Pandas cannot handle comparing a list to anything using `==` because it's not clear what answer you want, so it's prompting you to explain.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html

I don't think you are trying to do that at all, but it's not clear what you are expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to check if `df.b`, a `List`, is equal to an `int`.

Try this:

```
if 2 in df.b:
   df.c=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off. you're trying to use a conditional on an entire dictionary!

You're basically saying "if this dicitonary == 2", which simply is an ambiguous statement because that dictionary (df.b) is a set of values, which doesn't necessarily evaluate to "true"...

df.b is

```
0     2
1     3
2    10
3     3
```

Honestly, based on your question, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to evaluate!  You should try printing df before you evaluate in the sub-ccomposition of df.b.